# Running vispr throws EmptyDataError when importing pandas.io.common

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to run the tool [vispr](https://bitbucket.org/liulab/vispr/src/master/) in able to visualize the results of the [mageck-vispr](https://bitbucket.org/liulab/mageck-vispr/src/master/) run.
I have installed everything as explained on the website within a conda environment.

Unfortunately, when running the command

```
vispr server results/GSC.vispr.yaml
```

it throws an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/fs/home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/bin/vispr", line 6, in <module>
    from vispr.cli import main
  File "/fs/home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vispr/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from vispr.results import Screens, Screen
  File "/fs/home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vispr/results/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from vispr.results import rna
  File "/fs/home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vispr/results/rna.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas.io.common import EmptyDataError
ImportError: cannot import name 'EmptyDataError' from 'pandas.io.common' (/fs/home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py)
```

From what I could find online, this exception might happens, when trying to read an empty file, but all the entries listed in the called `GSC.vispr.yaml` file exists and are not empty.

I would appreciate it, if someone can help me narrow down the problem or offer a solution.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if the solution I have found is the right one, but all I did is to comment out line 14 in `rna.py`

```
import pandas as pd
# from pandas.io.common import EmptyDataError
import numpy as np
```

Now `vispr` is working.